# What are the setting required in Joomla to upload make it live with all the hosting and domain details?

Tags: joomla, hosting

I Have all the hosting, control panel  and domain details available with me.

what are the settings required to upload the website on Live?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Upload files via FTP to domains public_html or www folder
2. Now edit configuration.php file, and replace these informations

   var $user = 'username-of-mysql-account';

   var $password = 'password-of-mysql-account';

   var $tmp_path = 'path-to-temporary-folder';

   var $log_path = 'path-to-store-logs';

   var $db = 'name-of-mysql-database';
3. Now website is ready to use

Answer (score 1):

Try [Akeeba Backup](http://www.akeebabackup.com/software/akeeba-backup.html) in order to move it onto another server :

- Install Akabee Backup Core to the existing Joomla! Site
- Make a Backup
- Upload Akabee Kickstart and the Backup file to the new Server
- Call the uploaded kickstart.php and follow the directions.

If you prefer the manual way: it is basically copying all files, the joomla! Database, and modifying some path-related directives in the configuration.php.